# Show/bind XML data in MessageBox

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm currently working on a WP7 app where I'm using an XML schema. One of the tags is like the following:

```
<Credit>http://www.somewebsite.com/credit</Credit>
```

I would like to be able to click a button, which again opens a messagebox that shows something like:

*Credit:
http://www.somewebsite.com/credit
*

Here's how's my app is made:

1. You're given a listbox of stuff you can click on.
2. When you click one of the items, you're transferred to a "template page", which'll be    filled with information from the XML schema.
3. Then I want to give the user the ability to click a button, a messagebox shows up with the `<Credit></Credit>` content for that specific XML part.

Comment: Well, I don't really know where I should start. I tried to implement C# code in XAML inside the <button></button> with <x:Code> and CDATA, but no luck ("The tag "Code" does not exist..").

Comment: OK, so you are at square one. Can I recommend you do a bit of reading first? Try this excellent free ebook: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx

Comment: Hello again Colin. Thanks for the tip. I'll continue reading on it, I started with it last week, but all of the suddenly I came to a point where I was doing more advanced stuff than my progress in the book.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a viewmodel, where in one property should contain the credits.